# R Language: Calculating an average across a subset of rows between a certain date and saving the results to a new dataframe

Tags: r, function, dataframe

usually I can find the answers to questions from a combination of Google and searching on StackOverflow, but this time I am a little stuck. I have a dataframe that contains some values collected on certain dates across multiple years. Here is a sample:

```
        "Date"      "TEMP"  "TEMP2"
"1"     2007-06-19  NA      NA
"2"     2007-06-19  24.4    22
"3"     2007-06-19  24.4    22
"4"     2007-06-19  NA      NA
"5"     2007-06-19  25.1    22.65
"6"     2007-06-19  NA      NA
"7"     2007-06-19  25.29   22.94
"8"     2007-06-19  25.20   22.69
"9"     2007-06-19  NA      NA
"10"    2007-06-19  25.20   22.69
"11"    2007-06-19  NA      NA
"12"    2007-06-19  25.9    23.94
```

What I want to do is create a new datatable (let's call it `df2`) that has averages for `Temp` and `Temp2` on a per-month basis. The output needs to be in this format and the `NA`'s need to be excluded:

```
        "DateFrom"      "DateTo"        "avg_TEMP"  "avg_TEMP2"
"1"     2007-06-1       2007-06-30      12.3        22.5
"2"     2007-07-1       2007-07-30      13.4        33.4
```

I have created a stub of `df2` and populated it with `DateFrom` and `DateTo` for the ranges I am interested in. As a programmer I know I can solve this with a for loop, but I do not think that is the correct way to approach the problem in R. Based on my limited understanding of R and other answers I've reviewed I need to use some form of the `apply` function on `df2`. I tried the code below, but I think I am just misunderstanding how `apply`, etc, work, because it didn't work.

```
get.daterange <- function(df, date1, date2) {
  df[df$Date >= date1 & df$Date <= date2,]
  tmp <- subset((df[df$Date >= date1 & df$Date <= date2,]),select=data.reportval)
  tmp.1 = colMeans(tmp, na.rm = TRUE)
  return(tmp.1)
}

df2 <- mapply(get.daterange, df1, df2$DateFrom, df2$DateTo)
```

The function probably has some problem... it works correctly if I give it two single values (so I could iterate across `df2` with a for loop and use it), but does not seem to do the correct thing if given dataframe columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend using the `lubridate` and `dplyr` packages. `lubridate` helps with date-time manipulation and `dplyr helps with data frame manipulation. Then, you can use something like this:

```
df2 <- df %>%
  mutate(month = month(Date), year = year(Date)) %>%
  group_by(month, year) %>%
  summarize(avg_TEMP = mean(TEMP, na.rm = TRUE),
            avg_TEMP2 = mean(TEMP2, na.rm = TRUE),
            std_TEMP = sd(TEMP, na.rm = TRUE),
            std_TEMP2 = sd(TEMP2, na.rm = TRUE),
            number_of_records = n(),
            non_NA_records = sum(!is.na(TEMP)))
```

So, the first line adds month and year columns, the second *groups* the data frame by those columns, and the third calculates the average temperatures for every group.

**EDIT**: added standard deviations and record count. You probably don't want to use `apply()` to work with data frames; dplyr is tailor-made for the purpose and `apply()` will only give you headaches, as it is designed for working with lists.

The book [R for data science](http://r4ds.had.co.nz) is very helpful for this sort of task

Comment: Thanks, this did work well. Thanks for the link to the book, I'll definately have a look. By chance, do you happen to know of a way to solve this using `apply`, because I also need to obtain counts of how many records are there, std dev, etc?

Comment: using n() will count the NA's as records though, no? (i.e. I want count of TEMP != na, count of TEMP2 != na). But thanks for the help, I'm sure I can figure it out from here!

Comment: I've added the non-NA counts above

Comment: Yup, a quick Google told me that sum() was the way to go too. Thanks again for your help, I've accepted your answer as the solution.

Comment: Say, is it also possible to add a column to the resulting dataframe that contains the date in "YYYY-MM" form without having to do `df2$Date <- (string_from_month_year)` after?